# JAX-RS forward post request

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, forwarding

I have a need where one api receives a form-data post request and after some processing I need forward the request to another api.

My first api is :

```
    @Path("/integrator/api") 
    public class IntegratorREST {

    @Context private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Context private HttpServletResponse response;

    @Context private ServletContext _context;

    @POST
    @Path("/go")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Object forwardLink(@Context UriInfo info) throws URISyntaxException, ServletException, IOException {


        (... my code ...)

        // For simple CORS requests, the server only needs to add these 2 header parameters that allow access to any client.
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        RequestDispatcher rd = _context.getRequestDispatcher("/uploadfile/api/send");
        rd.forward(request, response);

        return null;

    }

}
```

The second api is:

```
@Path("/uploadfile/api")
public class UploadFileREST {

private String DIRECTORY = 
        "../../pentaho-solutions/system/uploadfile/";

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@POST
@Path("/send")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("application/json")
public Output uploadFile(
        @Context UriInfo info,
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    (... code to upload a file to server ...)

}
```

So, the rd.forward() in the first api is executed, but nothing happen in the second one, I mean, I have breakpoint in the first line but the code is not executed.

Also, I dont get no warning/error message in the console.

How can I forward my post request to another endpoint ?

Thanks for any help.

Kleyson Rios.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to call the second API using REST service call, using API's like Apache HTTPClient or something similar.

Regards,
Hunaid.

Comment: And how to use the post parameters passed to the first API ? Because one of then it's a file to uploaded.

Comment: Refer this link for the complete code http://www.java-redefined.com/2014/04/rest-client-java-using-apache-http-client.html